# Proving that a differentiable function is subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

Here I am stuck at a problem from Advanced Calulus by Loomis and Sternberg.

Let $A$ be the open interval $(0,1)$, and let $V$ be $\mathbb R^A$. Given a point $x$ in $(0,1)$,
let $V_x$ be the set of functions in $V_x$ that have a derivative at $x$. Show that $V_x$ is a sub-space of $V$.

Silly of me, but how should I proceed with this problem?

Comment: What have you tried? Assuming hou have tried something, it would be a good idea to edit it into your question.

Comment: Make use of the second sentence in the 'Definition' section of this link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_subspace#Definition

Comment: @C-RAM -_- My apologies, but all i did was to write that $V_{x} = \{f : f$ is differentiable at $x\}$. From there, i assumed that $\frac{df}{dx} = y$, to prove that it's a subspace it should satisfy the three conditions : (i) If ${y = 0}$, then  $\vec{0} \in V_{x}$. For the condition two, can i assume that if $g \in V_{x}$ then $\frac{dg}{dx} = y$, hah, this is where i am stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $V_x=\{f:(0,1)\to \Bbb{R}|\ f\text{ is differentiable at $x$}\}$. Clearly $0_V:(0,1)\to \Bbb{R}\in V_x$. Let $f,g\in V_x$. It’s easy to check, $(f+g)’(x)=f’(x)+g’(x)$. Thus $f+g\in V_x$. Let $c\in \Bbb{R}$ and $f\in V_x$. Then $(c\cdot f)’(x)=c\cdot f’(x)$. Thus $c\cdot f\in V_x$. Hence $V_x$ is subspace of $V=R^{A}$.

Just use definition of derivative of a real function.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution!